# In Android application, when to use View control instead of Tab

Tags: navigation, android, tabs, spinner

I develop a shopping application for one company. First time I design to use Tab to categorize product in shop. But I am not sure Ishould use "View control" instead of "Tab" or not.

[image: View control vs Tab]

Tab and View Control have the same functionality to allow users to explore and switch between View. It should have a better reason than "It's looking good when use View Control"

If It has some principle on Android. It will be easy to design application next time. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, **both tabs and spinners are view controls** in the Android Design Guidelines.  To quote from them:

[image]

However, dealing with when you should use tabs vs spinners, it is primarily a question of space and design.

- **Spinners** take up **less space** and allow the user to (usually) see all of the options at once.
  [image]
- **Fixed tabs** display all items concurrently, but take up **more space** and are only workable with a few categories with short titles.
  [image]
- **Scrolling tab** controls take up **less space** and can contain a larger number of items than a standard tab control, but don't let a user see all of the items at the same time, and so requires **more exploration**.  Technically you can have many sections, but practically it is not a good idea to have more than about 4 of them.
  [image]