# Choosing between Tabs and ActionBar spinner

Tags: android, tabs, spinner, tab-bar

I need to show group of objects in two ways: in the list and on the map. I can use tabs or action bar spinner. As Android guide says both modes are acceptable ([In Android application, when to use View control instead of Tab](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/38580/in-android-application-when-to-use-view-control-instead-of-tab)). But because of map there're few problems:

- tab mode works with swipe gesture and when user is on the map he can't swipe to the list (because map intercept gestures to be draggable). Thus to see map he can swipe or tap on the tab, but to see the list he needs to tap on the tab only.
- I think that spinner mode looks not so obvious in my case. One element in the dropped menu looks strange.

Is there better way of showing/switching map and list?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Smartcoupons uses a button next to the overflow button. when you're on the list, it shows an image of a pin, like the one you can place on a map. When you're in the map, it shows the facebook-like hamburger menu icon, which is 3 horizontal stripes. I think the icons could use a bit of work, but I like the idea.

[image]

[image]

I like this icon for switching to the map interface:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I can't help much with alternative, but album on my Android phone has exactly what you describe and it's ok, map is movig, so I get I need to tap on tab - the primary action taken on tabs since they were invented. Don't you want to test it with people around you to be sure if you hesitate and do not struggle working around the swipe on map?